# xBaseJ update not working

Tags: java, dbf

I have a 'DBF' file I need to update a column from my field, I am using xBaseJ API to do the 'DBF' manipulations, my code as follows:

```
         DBF classDB=new DBF("ABC.dbf");

        NumField xval = (NumField) classDB.getField("X"); 
        classDB.read();
        System.out.println(" X= " + xval.get());  
        xval.update(xval++);
```

Update not working. please help guys

Answer (score 0):

You have to .put() values into the items that you want to change. Then you call .update() on the DB item:

```
DBF classDB=new DBF("ABC.dbf");

NumField xval = (NumField) classDB.getField("X"); 
classDB.read();
System.out.println(" X= " + xval.get());  

// the .get() function returns a space padded string, so you need to .trim() 
// it and use Integer.parseInt() to make it an integer for the addition of 1
xval.put(Integer.parseInt(xval.get().trim()) + 1);

// Once all changes are made with one or more .put() calls use .update() 
// on the database itself
classDB.update();
```